# Sony A6000 failing to set exposure mode

Tags: camera, sony

I'm attempting to set the exposure mode of a Sony A6000 using smart remote version 2.0.1 by posting the following command: {'method': 'setExposureMode', 'params': ['Shutter'], 'id': 12, 'version': '1.0'}, but I'm getting back the following response: {u'id': 12, u'error': [500, u'Set operation failed.']}. I can't seem to find a description for error code 500 anywhere in the API documentation. I've used the same command to successfully set the exposure modes of NEX-5, NEX-6, and A5000 cameras. Is there something different I need to be doing for the A6000?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing different as far as I am aware of. Please check code and other general things like current camera mode, also if camera has latest firmware, latest "Smart Remote Control" app, etc,.
Best Regards, Prem, Developer World team